# Stockfish for python not working correctly, how to fix this?

Tags: python, chess, stockfish

I'm writing a chess puzzle solver using stockfish. I'm using the python interfacing of stockfish as described here.
https://pypi.org/project/stockfish/

Like the author told, I installed the stockfish engine from the terminal of my can and ran the code below. It throws an error "AttributeError: 'Stockfish' object has no attribute '_stockfish.'
"

```
from stockfish import Stockfish
stockfish = Stockfish()

stockfish.set_position(['e2e4', 'e7e6'])
```

How do I fix the issue?

The code the author wrote is this.'

```
from stockfish import Stockfish

stockfish = Stockfish(path="/Users/zhelyabuzhsky/Work/stockfish/stockfish-9-64")
```

but how do I find the path to a program installed in mac?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: if it is executable program which you can run in console as  `stockfish` then you may try to use `which stockfish` to get full path.

Comment: @furas thank you. I'm learning python and it was a beginners mistake

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73566499/how-to-replace-the-executable-file-when-a-program-run-on-a-windows-is-ported-to

Answer (score 1):

The [stockfish package](https://pypi.org/project/stockfish/) is only a python interface for stockfish, you need to either [compile it from the source](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish#compiling-stockfish-yourself-from-the-sources), or [download an executable](https://stockfishchess.org/download/).

Once you have the executable, simply provide a path to the `Stockfish` constructor as in the example.

```py
from stockfish import Stockfish
stockfish = Stockfish(path="/Users/zhelyabuzhsky/Work/stockfish/stockfish-15-64")

stockfish.set_position(['e2e4', 'e7e6'])
```