# How to replace the executable file when a program run on a windows is ported to mac?

Tags: python, chess, stockfish

The following code works fine on a PC, but how do I make it work on a mac? The problem is how do I get the link to the stockfish executable on a mac? I'm having trouble porting the line three onto a mac (pycharm). I have installed stockfish via brew but confused how I should write the line three equivalent on a mac.

```
import chess
import chess.engine

engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(r"C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\stockfish_14_win_x64\stockfish_14_win_x64_avx2.exe")

board = chess.Board()
while not board.is_game_over():
    result = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=0.1))
    board.push(result.move)

engine.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go in the Finder, and search any executable file named stockfish (using cmd+f). Next, just take the path of this file and replace it in your code.
If you face an erno 13 permission denied, you will have to open the terminal app, and type
`chmod +x your_stockfish_path`